# Tomcat Class Loader : priority between WebappX & Common

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have 3 applications that are deployed on Tomcat (version 9.02)

- WS
- app
- admin

The applications use a common jar, added by me and which is in `$CATALINA_BASE / lib`

When I call the **WS**, it has a lib which is also in the **common jar** but with another version, which throws an exception. If I delete this lib on the **WS** => it works! Does this mean that the common jar also uses * WS * libs? Normally **WS** resources are not be visible to other applications, or even to other server.

My question is : What do I do such that **WS** libs will not be used by lib on **$CATALINA_BASE/lib**

I read this:
[Class Loader HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html) but it does not help much

thx

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [Class Loader HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html) :

> Therefore, from the perspective of a web application, class or resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:
>
> ```
> Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
> System class loader classes (described above)
> Common class loader classes (described above)
> ```
>
> If the web application class loader is configured with `<Loader delegate="true"/>` then the order becomes:
>
> ```
> Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> System class loader classes (described above)
> Common class loader classes (described above)
> /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
> /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
> ```

I think it is pretty evident what should you do if you want your webapp libs to have higher priority over libs in the common.

As for

> My question is : What do I do such that WS libs will not be used by lib on $CATALINA_BASE/lib

It is the code in your webapplication (WS) that loads $CATALINA_BASE/lib or libs in WS. If you have a class that is present in $CATALINA_BASE/lib and not in WS/lib, the class in $CATALINA_BASE/lib will be used and if this class references other classes that are in WS, the classes from WS will be loaded (assuming you don't have `<Loader delegate="true"/>`

Comment: thanks for your feedback, when I add '<Loader delegate = "true" />' on `conf / context.xml` to invert, also the same error (a conflict)